# how to compare text on web page with text in external file in web driver?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I am trying it by below code:-

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("TC5_data.txt"));
String str;
while ((str = in .readLine()) != null) {
 System.out.println(str); {
  String str1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='content']/div[2]/table/tbody/tr/td[1]")).getText();
  if (str.equals(str1)) {
   System.out.println("Data is Matching");
  } else {
   System.out.println("Data is not Matching");
  }
```

But above code is not working for me... need help urgntly

Answer (score 0):

These are the necersary imports:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
```

And this is a method that will allow you to read from a File by passing it the filename as a parameter like this: readFile("yourFile.txt");

```
String readFile(String fileName) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
    try {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = br.readLine();

        while (line != null) {
            sb.append(line);
            sb.append("\n");
            line = br.readLine();
        }
        return sb.toString();
    } finally {
        br.close();
    }
}
```

To compare the String you need to use `equalsIgnoreCase` function

Use below code for condition :-

```
if(str.equalsIgnoreCase(str1))
{
    System.out.println("Equal");
}else{
    System.out.println("Not Equal");
}
```

Hope it will help you :)

Comment: Why are you advising OP to use `equalsIgnoreCase` rather than original `equals`?